# Pull data from wordpress database - unknown format

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, utf-8, longtext

I need help pulling data from the field with unknown format of data structure. I am using a wordpress quiz plugin and i want to pull data from its backend table.
Data stored in answer_data is:

```
a:4:{
i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:17:"Kieran Trippier ";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}

i:1;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:11:"Hugo Lloris";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}

i:2;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:14:"Moussa Dembele";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:0;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}

i:3;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"*_answer";s:14:"Jan Vertonghen";s:8:"*_html";b:0;s:10:"*_points";i:1;s:11:"*_correct";b:1;s:14:"*_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"*_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"*_mapper";N;}
}
```

while looking at the structure of the table, data type of answer_data is longtext but has   **utf8_general_ci** alongside it. I dont know what this means.
From this data i want to pull, quiz answers i.e.Kieran Trippier,Hugo Lloris,Moussa Dembele and Jan Vertonghen.
Any help or hint will be very much appreciated.

EDIT 1:

```
Array ( 
[0] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => Kieran Trippier [_html:protected] => [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => [_mapper:protected] => ) 
[1] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => Hugo Lloris [_html:protected] => [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => [_mapper:protected] => ) 
[2] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => Moussa Dembele [_html:protected] => [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => [_mapper:protected] => ) 
[3] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => Jan Vertonghen [_html:protected] => [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => 1 [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => [_mapper:protected] => ) )
```

how to get values from this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is some form of serialization.  It seems to be an array `a` of 4 elements, each of which is further structure.  The plugin understands; you probably don't need to understand it.

`utf8_general_ci` is the "Collation" to be used for comparing the `LONGTEXT` strings.  It implies `CHARACTER SET utf8`, which is the 3-byte subset of `UTF-8` (aka, MySQL's `utf8mb4`).  This allows you to include characters from most languages around the world.

One would hope that the plugin provides a way to dissect this structure, rather than leaving you guessing.  Furthermore, the plugin could change the structure without notice.

Here's the hint:  See PHP's `serialize()` and `unserialize()`.

Using the unserialized result:

`$foo` seems to be an array of 'objects' of `class` `WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes`.  One of the 'properties' of that object seems to be `$_answer`.  So, see if this gives you the list of answers:

```
foreach($foo as $obj) {
    echo $obj->_answer, "\n";
}
```

Or, to grab the answers into an array `$answers`:

```
$answers = array();
foreach($foo as $obj) {
    $answers[] = $obj->_answer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint.. unserialize() function helped to convert into Array. But i am having trouble pulling data from this array. Can you help? please see the edit portion.
Regards

Comment: @SujanShrestha - See if my code snippet helps more.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer. Sorry, I am late. I was away with other stuffs.
Can you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663434/get-values-from-protected-property