# Get values from protected property

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, protected

I am having issues with accessing the protected property. I am trying to query a database table of wordpress. Following is my code:

```
    <?php
    $table_name = 'wp_wp_pro_quiz_question';
    $current_quiz_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT max(quiz_id) as quiz_id FROM $table_name");

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name where quiz_id = $current_quiz_id");
  if(!empty($results)){
     foreach($results as $row){?>
     // print_r($row->answer_data);
     print_r(unserialize($row->answer_data));
     $answer_data = unserialize($row->answer_data);
     $answers = array();
     foreach($answer_data as $obj) {
     $answers[] = $obj->get_answer;
     }
     print_r($answers);
     }           
    ?>
```

print_r(unserialize($row->answer_data)) gives following result:

```
Array ( 
[0] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => 26 [_html:protected] => 1 [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => 1 [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => 1 [_mapper:protected] => ) 
[1] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => 6 [_html:protected] => 1 [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => 1 [_mapper:protected] => ) 
[2] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => 4 [_html:protected] => 1 [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => 1 [_mapper:protected] => ) 
[3] => WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes Object ( [_answer:protected] => 16 [_html:protected] => 1 [_points:protected] => 1 [_correct:protected] => [_sortString:protected] => [_sortStringHtml:protected] => 1 [_mapper:protected] => ) )
```

I used **get** to access the protected field. I pushed all the values to the array $answers but i am getting all values null.
Result of print_r($answers):
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )

What am i doing wrong here?

Thank You

Comment: You just can't access protected properties unless you are in the inheritance chain.

Comment: @vivek_23: How can i inherit the access then?

Comment: Use all the getter methods as shown here https://github.com/wcorrigan/portals/blob/master/plugins/sfwd-lms/wp-pro-quiz/lib/model/WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes.php

Answer (score -2):

Replace the two selects with one:

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name
    ORDER BY quiz_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then replace `*` by the list of columns that you want.

Comment: How will this help in accessing protected property?